# jQuery issue with drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Problems are:

- The drop down `menu(#sub-button)` is closing by mouse click, it should close only when click on visible `#button`
- When for example I try to open second drop down `menu(#sub-button2)` the first drop down menu should close immediately when click on `#button2`

Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jquery ddm</title>
<style type="text/css">
#button {
    position:fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#sub-button {
    display: none;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:41px;
    background-color:cyan;
}
#button2 {
    position:fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
background-color:orange;
}
#sub-button2 {
    display: none;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:41px;
    background-color:aqua;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button">
        <div id="sub-button">6</div>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="button2" style="margin-left:152px;">
        <div id="sub-button2">66</div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>
```

and the js code (toggle.js):

```
var myTimeout;
// show/hide sub-button menu
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $( "#sub-button" ).toggle();
});
// if mouse out of button and sub-button divs - close sub-button after 860ms
$( "#button" ).mouseout(function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout( "jQuery('#sub-button').hide();",860 );
});
// if timer that are about to close sub-button is launched, stop it
// by hover button or sub-button divs
$( "#button" ).mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});

var myTimeout2;
$( "#button2" ).click(function() {
    $( "#sub-button2" ).toggle();
});
$( "#button2" ).mouseout(function() {
    myTimeout2 = setTimeout( "jQuery('#sub-button2').hide();",860 );
});
$( "#button2" ).mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout2);
});
```

Comment: lee_gladding thanks for suggestion, it's not only done the problems but I clearly understand you'r code and can make some changes or make another buttons. Really thanks! ReDEyeS, thank you too for respond, i will take this part of code into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the submenu is a child of the `#button`, so the click event will bubble up to the parent and the code for the `#button` click event will get called.

The first issue you can solve by testing for the original clicked target:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'button'){

        $( "#sub-button" ).toggle();

    }

});
```

The second issue is that no where in your code are you closing the first button on click of the second button and visa versa

you could add:

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'button') {
        $("#sub-button2").hide();
        $("#sub-button").toggle();
    }

});
```

Although if you are going to have more buttons later on, this JS can and should be tidied up and made more efficient, otherwise you risk the code becoming hard to maintain.

here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/mV3Ba/)

Answer (score 1):

just change your js like this:

```
var myTimeout;

// show/hide sub-button menu

$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $("#sub-button2").hide();
    if (!$("#sub-button2").is(":visible")) $( "#sub-button" ).show();

});

// if mouse out of button and sub-button divs - close sub-button after 860ms

$( "#button" ).mouseout(function() {

myTimeout = setTimeout( "jQuery('#sub-button').hide();",860 );

});

// if timer that are about to close sub-button is launched, stop it

// by hover button or sub-button divs

$( "#button" ).mouseover(function() {

clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});

var myTimeout2;

$( "#button2" ).click(function() {
    if (!$("#sub-button2").is(":visible")) $( "#sub-button2" ).show();
    $("#sub-button").hide();
});

$( "#button2" ).mouseout(function() {

myTimeout2 = setTimeout( "jQuery('#sub-button2').hide();",860 );

});

$( "#button2" ).mouseover(function() {

clearTimeout(myTimeout2);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly, you want to prevent the event bubble to the parent, and if you click a menu, hide the other menus child.  No need to do a bunch of "checking", just handle the events properly.  Note where I comment "ADD" below

Rush to the example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gP4CV/

```
var myTimeout;
// show/hide sub-button menu
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#sub-button").toggle();
    $("#sub-button2").hide();// ADD hide other child
});
// ADD prevent event bubble to parent
$("#sub-button, #sub-button2").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
// if mouse out of button and sub-button divs - close sub-button after 860ms
$("#button").mouseout(function () {
    myTimeout = setTimeout("jQuery('#sub-button').hide();", 860);
});
// if timer that are about to close sub-button is launched, stop it
// by hover button or sub-button divs
$("#button").mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});

var myTimeout2;
$("#button2").click(function () {
    $("#sub-button2").toggle();
    $("#sub-button").hide(); // ADD hide other child
});
$("#button2").mouseout(function () {
    myTimeout2 = setTimeout("jQuery('#sub-button2').hide();", 860);
});
$("#button2").mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout2);
});
```